# Remove matching pairs of rows from query

Tags: sql

I am trying to produce a report from an SQL database.

The data is transactions, sometimes because of operator error incorrect records are entered, latter to correct for this the same record is entered but with a negative quantity.

i.e.

```
ID, DESC  , QTY
0 , ITEM1 , 2
1 , ITEM2 , 1
2 , ITEM3 , 2     // This record and
3 , ITEM2 , 1
4 , ITEM3 , -2    // this record cancel out
```

I would like to have a query that looks at pairs of rows that are identical besides the ID and have an opposite sign on the QTY and does not include them in the result.

Similar to the below.

```
ID, DESC  , QTY
0 , ITEM1 , 2
1 , ITEM2 , 1
3 , ITEM4 , 1
```

What is the easiest way I can achieve this in a query. I was thinking along the lines of an aggregate SUM function, but I only wanted to remove rows with a QTY of opposite sign but equal magnitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather painful.  The immediate answer to your question is `not exists`.  However, you need to be careful about duplicates, so I would recommend enumerating the values first:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by desc, qty order by id) as seqnum
      from transactions t
     )
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.desc = t.desc and
                        t2.seqnum = t.seqnum and
                        t2.qty = - t.qty
                 );
```

Comment: Thankyou, although I note I should have been more careful with my example field names, desc causes syntax errors due to conflict with the keyword.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `left join` antipattern to evict records for which another record exists with the same `desc` and an opposite `qty`.

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.desc = t.desc and t1.qty = - t.qty
where t1.id is null
```

Or a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.desc = t.desc and t1.qty = - t.qty
)
```

Comment: I went with Gordon's answer in this case because of the check for duplicates, which in this case matters. I appreciate seeing how join can be used though.